# Вывод скрипта для option с атрибутом selected

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Помогите подредактировать скрипт jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#order').bind('change',function(){
        $('#order_price').html($('#order option:selected').attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Этот скрипт добавляет в блок с `#order_price` значение из атрибута `title` тега `option`. Но проблема заключается в том, что скрипт срабатывает при условии переключения option'ов и поэтому, если для option задан атрибут `selected`, то ничего в блоке не выводится. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось сразу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто написать функцию и вызвать ее, когда DOM модель будет готова:

```
$(function(){
  function start(){
    $('#order_price').html($('#order option:selected').attr('title'));
  }
  start();
});
```

Как-то так...

Comment: Я бы дополнил чуток:

    function setPrice(){
        $('#order_price').html($('#order :selected').attr('title'));
    }
    setPrice();
    $('#order').on('change',setPrice);

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но я понимаю обьявление и использование функции в вашем коде так же как:

    var a;
    a=1;

вместо этого:

    var a=1;

Тоесть код написаный вами работает так же как более простой:

    $(function(){
      $('#order_price').html($('#order option:selected').attr('title'));
    });

Если я ошибаюсь — обьясните, пожалуйста, уместность создания функции здесь.

Comment: Да, можно использовать вариант, который предлагаете Вы. Кому как больше нравится...

Comment: @eprivalov1, в чём здесь привычка? Это просто ненужные действия, не более.

Comment: Если программа состоит из 10 строк кода, то конечно Ваш метод предпочтительнее, а если из 10000 строк кода, то лучше все, что только можно разбивать на функции. Удобнее искать, редактировать, работать... Можно сделать библиотеку функций и вынести ее в отдельный файл. Это личное предпочтение каждого так сказать..

Answer (score 2):

Может нужно просто вызвать функцию при загрузке DOM?

```
$(function(){
    $('#order').bind('change',function(){
        $('#order_price').html($('#order option:selected').attr('title'));
    });
    $('#order').change();
});
```

Только желательно оптимизировать код, а именно:

1. Заменить `.bind('change',function(){...})` на `.change(function(){...}`;
2. Убрать второй вызов `$('#order')`;
3. Заменить поиск `$('#order option:selected')` на поиск среди дочерних эллементов.

Результат:

```
$(function(){
    $('#order').change(function(){
        $('#order_price').html($(this).children(':selected').attr('title'));
    }).change();
});
```